# how to unit-test nested functions and JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Joined project as total newbee. My task is to make unit-tests for existing JS code.

The overall project web-site system works like (as i get it): Python + Django contains all logic, database and rules over html templates, when JS files works as "widgets" that helping to edit html-code on page.

Mostly all the JS files are like:

```js
var WidgetSmart = (function() {
    var map
    function create_event() {
        $('.leaflet-pm-toolbar').addClass('leaflet-pm-toolbar-disable')
        /*
         * lines of code
         */
        another_function();
    }
    function another_function(){
        /*
         * lines of code
         */
    }

    return {
        init: function(map_obj) {
          map = map_obj
          create_event()
        }
    };
}());
```

As my co-worker said all `return` stuff is for safety reasons (incapsulation of methods).

1. For this example as i suppose, i need to check the work of `create_event` function (and `another_function`?), but how to select and test only this piece?
2. How to unit-test this files correctly? (by using mocks or another extra?) Or is it necessary to rebuild this code?

Comment: You don't. You test through the public API, the init method. Otherwise you're breaking the encapsulation then IIFE is there to provide.